# cordova-plugin-firebase is not working in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

i want integration cordova-plugin-firebase in ionic 3

added this plugin

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase@4

i got error like this

ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other
libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0], [17.2.2,17.2.2]], but resolves to 17.2.2.
Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

then i add this plugin

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable play-services-location=17.0.0

Build Failed

WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
>   Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild FAILED
>   3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

ionic info

ionic info

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 8.1.0 browser 5.0.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.2
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: This has been a long standing issue, there are several solutions out there including doing it manually. Here's a plugin that claims to fix it. https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release

Comment: I switched to [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) a while ago and haven't had any problems since. There's also [an Ionic native wrapper](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x).